# unable want to check length of list, i want to check list length greater than 0 than loop over it and render each element

Tags: python, jinja2

Trying to loop over  a list , and then show each element of that list in span element, but its not working first I want to check if length of that list is greater than 0 than loop over the list , I am not familiar  with syntax , need help .

code:

```
  {%if len(prediction)>0%}
  {%for predict in prediction%}
  <span>{{predict}}</span>
  ​{% endfor %}
```

Comment: maybe you didn't end `if` statement, add `{% endif %}`

Comment: I think `jinja2` tag is better than `flask` and `django`. I doubt you use both frameworks simultaneously. And in any case the question is not framework dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% if prediction|length > 0 %}
  {% for predict in prediction %}
    <span>{{predict}}</span>
  ​{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Try this, you can use "|length" to get length, if you want equal can use "length_is"

Like this:

```
{{ value|length_is:"0" }}
```